# How to Whitelist Authorization header in cloudfront custom origin request policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

cross post from serverfault

https://serverfault.com/questions/1053906/how-to-whitelist-authorization-header-in-cloudfront-custom-origin-request-policy

The post in question, I am also running into and am seeking an answer for. I have to use the AWS-CDK and cloudformation so using non legacy work around would be ideal

I tried to make a new origin request policy that would pass through all viewer headers and I see it in my request header (authorization) but get cors
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have 3 ways to forward the Authorization header:

1- Create an origin request policy and select "All viewer headers" under header options.

You cannot forward the Authorization header individually in an origin request policy, but when you forward all viewer headers CloudFront includes the Authorization header in viewer requests

2- Add the Authorization header to the cache key using a cache policy. All headers in the cache key are automatically included in origin requests

3- Use legacy cache settings

Unfortunately there is no other way around it.

Comment: In my case, when used 'All viewer headers' in origin request settings I got SignatureDoesNotMatch error from S3, but using 'Include the following headers' and setting  only 'Referer' header worked fine.